# Pass data from RecyclerView Adaptor to another activity

Tags: java, android

I have created a RecyclerView which populates the users' contacts with a checkbox.
When a user clicks on a checkbox, I want to add that contact to an Object.
Now I have been able to do that, but I am facing issues with sending that object from the adapter to another activity:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,  final int position){

  //  final PlayerDetails thePlayer = playerData.get(position);
  // ArrayList<PlayerDetails> thePlayer = playerData;
    //holder.playerNameNumber.setText(thePlayer.name + " " + thePlayer.number);
    holder.playerNameNumber.setText(playerData.get(position).name +playerData.get(position).number );

    holder.pickedPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View thisView){
            PlayerDetails contact = new PlayerDetails();
            contact.number = playerData.get(position).name;
            contact.name = playerData.get(position).number;
            playerListGame.addPlayer(contact);
            String name = playerData.get(position).name;
            Toast.makeText(thisView.getContext(),name + " added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });


}
```

When I debug the above, I can see playerListGame contains the data I am adding to it.

Now, I tried to do the following :

```
public PlayerList donePickingSendPlayers(){
   return playerListGame;
}
```

at the bottom of my adapter.
But when I debug, it shows that it has a value of 0. (I did initialise it at the start.

How can I send playerListGame to another activity?

I have set up a floating button, which onClick does the following:

```
private void donePicking(){
    ContactPickerRecyclerViewAdapter justToGetPlayerData = new ContactPickerRecyclerViewAdapter();
    justToGetPlayerData.donePickingSendPlayers();
    Intent backToComposeMessage = new Intent(this,ComposeMessage.class);
    startActivity(backToComposeMessage);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work as the playerListGame within "donePickingPlayers"
is empty.

Comment: You are doing more in your adapter than you have posted. Some of which is relevant to your question eg. what is `playerListGame`? What is its scope? ... Please post the entire adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the same object of adapter you have set in recyclerview while fetching data using your method created inside adapter.

```
private void donePicking(){
ContactPickerRecyclerViewAdapter justToGetPlayerData = new 
      ContactPickerRecyclerViewAdapter();
justToGetPlayerData.donePickingSendPlayers();
Intent backToComposeMessage = new Intent(this,ComposeMessage.class);
startActivity(backToComposeMessage);
```

}

in this method you are creating another instance of the adapter class which always gives you empty data.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean here. Is it possible you can explain with some code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Write an interface with method donePicking(PlayerDetails contact) in your adapter and implement that method in your activity and override method in your activity there you'll get PlayerDetails object in overridden method and you can pass it to next activity.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you wrote out the code for what you described

Comment: I could but at the moment I am not near to my computer. I am writing it from mobile. You can refer to this https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9 tutorial for now. It explains what I am saying.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wil give it ago and update the question after